# Alternatives to dynamically joining a table onto itself

Tags: c#, linq, join, dynamic

For some additional practice, I would like to create an application that will tell the user the route to take in order to join a table to another table.  The solution would be based on data input into a SQL table (demo #Test).

The best route I found would be to dynamically inner join the table onto itself until I reach the table it can join to (what I demo'd below).  I am not sure how to best automate this where a user would input any two tables to see if there are any possible join paths, any suggestions? C#/dynamic SQL using sp_execute SQL?

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    tbl1 varchar(20),
    tbl2 varchar(20),
    col  varchar(20)
)

insert into #Test Values ('A','B','c1')
insert into #Test Values ('A','C','c2')
insert into #Test Values ('A','B','c3')
insert into #Test Values ('B','D','c4')
insert into #Test Values ('D','F','c5')
insert into #Test Values ('F','H','c6')
insert into #Test Values ('C','Z','c7')
insert into #Test Values ('H','I','c8')

select * from #Test

select * 
  from #Test A
       inner join #Test B on a.tbl2 = b.tbl1
       inner join #Test C on b.tbl2 = c.tbl1
       inner join #Test D on c.tbl2 = D.tbl1
       inner join #Test e on d.tbl2 = e.tbl1
 where a.tbl1 = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

What database engine are you using? If the database you are using supports with statements, you may be able to use a recursive with statement.

In sqlite3 this would look like

```
WITH RECURSIVE #Test2 (tbl1, tbl2, col) AS (
    VALUES('A', 'B', 'c1')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT #Test.tbl1, #Test.tbl2, #Test.col
    FROM #Test,#Test2 WHERE #Test2.tbl2 = #Test.tbl1)
SELECT *
FROM #Test2;
```

Which should give you all of the paths from table A through table B to any other tables that are referenced.

I end up getting a result of:

```
A|B|c1
B|D|c4
D|F|c5
F|H|c6
H|I|c8
```

If you would like to get a different path from this, you need to change the values in the second line of the query to match a different record in the #Test table.

There are more things you can do by using multiple WITH statements, but I'm not entirely sure if you want the information presented differently or want to provide different input than that. Either way, I believe that you can get what you want by using WITH statements and playing with them is pretty fun :)

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2008 - would you say this would be SQL server's Common Table Expressions?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) which looks like CTE (Common Table Expressions) are akin to WITH Statements. The syntax looks pretty much the same as well.